# Ubuntu 16.10 stuck with Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)

Tags: laptop, 16.10, asus, display-resolution, gallium

Just reboot my laptop Asus Zenbook, with the last update and now I'm stuck with this Gallium driver with only 800*600 display in the settings ! instead of 1920*1080... And in the "About this computer" this Gallium driver has shown up instead of the usual one.

Can't do almost anything with this display. Have tried to boot from USB and it's working fine: hardware is ok and all displays size available. I have looked to othe post about the same Gallium problem:

- There is no additional drivers available under Software & Updates in System Settings. The only one (used/checked) is Processor microcode
  firmware for Intel CPU.
- LTS Enablement Stacks doesn't specify anything for 16.10
- Don't understand if using kernel 4.9 will do anything in my situation because I'm on a laptop and don't know if I have a graphic
  card.

So, I wonder what's the best way to get out of this situation ? Do I have to reinstall the system from USB or is there an easy trick ?

Please Help ...

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution.

- First I went in Synaptic, searched for Gallium, removed totally mesa-udpau-drivers (or something like that). It didn't make any improvement.
- And then I went to install 4.9 kernel following this instructions: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-linux-kernel-4-9-ubuntu-linux-mint/ . Reboot and ... Everything went back to normal :)